# Adding in links to vimdoc

Tags: discussion

When I post on AskUbuntu or Unix & Linux, I like to add links to manpages (such as [Ubuntu's](http://manpages.ubuntu.com), or [linux.die.net's](http://linux.die.net/man/)) of the commands that I use, or if someone posts an answer mentioning `man foo`, but doesn't link to an online version. I'd like to continue and encourage that practice here, with links to [Vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/). Thoughts?

Of course, it goes without saying that if I could improve the post in other ways, I'd do those alongside adding in links to Vimdoc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds like a useful and helpful thing to do, please continue.

There is also http://vimhelp.appspot.com/ which seems to be more up-to-date.